# Remix Warning: This looks like an address but has an invalid checksum

Tags: solidity, remix, addresses, checksum

I have the following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.13;


contract Test {

    function test() public payable {
        address(0xCF5609B003B2776699EEA1233F7C82D5695CC9AA).call(1);
    }
}
```

The Remix static code analysis tool gives me a warning:

> Warning: This looks like an address but has an invalid checksum.

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is how the address with the valid checksum should look like: 0xCf5609B003B2776699eEA1233F7C82D5695cC9AA (note the different case of letters).

Here is the specification of the checksum: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-55.md

To fix the checksum use this method [web3.utils.toChecksumAddress()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#tochecksumaddress).

Alternatively put your address to the url for etherscan like this https://etherscan.io/address/0xCF5609B003B2776699EEA1233F7C82D5695CC9AA then copy the address with valid checksum on the loaded page.