# Invalid address error

Tags: web3js, truffle, cpp-ethereum, infura

I keep getting `Error: Invalid address` when trying to run the application.
My current setup of web3 using infura node is

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/doeL97MLPLVXBgAnRZRJ');
  web3 = new Web3(provider);
}
web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.defaultAccount)
```

The instance of the contract is

```
const contract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
const instance = contract.at(address);
instance.web3.eth.defaultAccount=instance.web3.eth.coinbase;
```

when trying to do a call to the contract, the value returned is `undefined`

```
const count = await EmployeeStore.employeesCount().then(function(value) {
      console.log(parseInt(value));
    });
```

as shown in the picture below, web3 is injected correctly and able to retrieve the accounts.
[image: Web3 injected]

Comment: Could you be a little more specific and provide the address you are using? Are you referring to the contract address or your personal account address? This will help us answering your question better.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this due to invalid checksum, your address should have a valid checksum, it depends on the lower/upper case of characters in address.Refer to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30257/remix-warning-this-looks-like-an-address-but-has-an-invalid-checksum)